# Threading synchronism 101

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a doubt about threading basics. If I launch a new thread *T1*, the main thread has to wait for *T1* to join or can continue its execution without waiting?.

If it has to wait, can I make both the main and the new threads run asynchronously?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you does not call `join()` both thread executes concurrently. By default threads runs asynchronously. `join()` blocks the calling thread until a thread terminates.

---

I would like to add to make thread execute synchronised, concurrency control mechanisms are provided.

One can explore about [POSIX Threads Programming](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/)

Comment: Hi!. So, if I put in my code `t1.join()` the main thread will have to wait for it, right?.
Thanks!.

Comment: yes, if in main thread you calls `ti.join()` then main thread will waits.

Comment: Another little point, if I don't use `join()`, once the thread has finished the computation, it will reunite with the main thread on its own, isn't it?. I mean, it will destroy itself once is done. And what if the main thread finished before the other one?. Then this will end in undefined behaviour, right?.

Thanks.

Comment: If main thread dies then all its child thread will also terminates.

Comment: @KioMarv : CAUTION : All my answer is in context of C and by-default behaviour of thread..In python and Java there is concept of Demon thread also those are eligible to be alive even after main thread dies. There is a  important role of virtual machine in thread execution.

Comment: You can learn more about thread termination issues [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725429/thread-termination-issue-c-programming)

Comment: Don't worry!. I'm interested in C++ only. ust forgot to set that tag :D

And thanks for the link!.