# pthread_join on two infinite loop threads?

Tags: c, pthreads, posix

I just read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680224/posix-threads-problem/1680271#1680271) that when the main loop ends, any threads that have or have not had a chance to spawn are terminated. So I need to do a join on each thread to wait for it to return.

My problem is, how will I write a program in which I create 2 threads that run in an infinite loop? If I wait to join on an infinite thread, the second one will never get a chance to be created!

Comment: Create the two before joining on either one?

Comment: yeah @zneak is right. I realized it later. both the answers are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two of the primary uses of `pthread_join` are (1) a convenient way to block until a created thread completes; (2) you are actually interested in the result returned from the created thread in `pthread_join`.

If you have no further work to do in main and you are just blocking so as to prevent the entire process from terminating then you can exit main with `pthread_exit`.  Main will exit but the spawned threads will continue.

If you aren't interested in the return code anyway you could just as easily create the threads as detached and `pthread_exit` main.

Having an "infinite" loop in the created threads is not the best practice.  Generally you want to give the ability to the thread to shut itself down.  Internally to the thread, this could be an eof condition, closed socket, or whatever.  Normally you want to give the ability for the thread to shut itself down cleanly from one or more other external threads as well.  Checking for a switch inside the infinite loop and similar methods are the easiest way to accomplish this.  Otherwise you have to go the pthread_cancel route, catch signals, etc.  All a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with this sequence:

```
pthread_create thread1
pthread_create thread2
pthread_join thread1
pthread_join thread2
```

In other words, start *all* your threads before you try to join *any* of them. In more detail, you can start with something like the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *myFunc (void *id) {
    printf ("thread %p\n", id);
    return id;
}

int main (void) {
    pthread_t tid[3];
    int tididx;
    void *retval;

    // Try for all threads, accept less.

    for (tididx = 0; tididx < sizeof(tid) / sizeof(*tid); tididx++)
        if (pthread_create (&tid[tididx], NULL, &myFunc, &tid[tididx]) != 0)
            break;

    // Not starting any is pretty serious.

    if (tididx == 0)
        return -1;

    // Join to all threads that were created.

    while (tididx > 0) {
        pthread_join (tid[--tididx], &retval);
        printf ("main %p\n", retval);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This will try to start three threads before joining on any, and then it will join to all those that it managed to get going, in reverse order. The output, as expected, is:

```
thread 0x28cce4
thread 0x28cce8
thread 0x28ccec
main 0x28ccec
main 0x28cce8
main 0x28cce4
```